# WP Query ignores variable for specific category

Tags: wordpress, categories

Ok I'm probably missing something obvious here since it's a really simple thing, but for some reason I can't get this WP Query to work. I want to query posts only from the category page that the user is currently visiting (using get_the_category). Like so -

```
$category = get_the_category();
$category_id = $category[0]->cat_ID;

$category_items = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => $category_id,
    'showposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
    )
);
```

$category_id gives me the correct ID for the category page, but referring to it inside WP Query makes the query get all my posts regardless of category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$category = get_the_category();
$category_name = $category[0]->cat_name;

$category_items = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => $category_name,
    'showposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
    )
);
```

Comment: That worked splendid, thanks! How come I can't use the ID for this?

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems to me like showposts = -1 overrides the cat parameter.

Comment: That's strange. Oh well, this solution will do just fine. Again, thanks!